# How to change sub Scene at Unity whtn I use MIRROR NETWORK?

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, unity3d-mirror

Hello? I try to do change scene while I use Mirror Network.

Firstly, this is a picture that my projects' scene structure and describe what I want to do:
[image]

And this is a capture image of my unity projects that you can understand my jobs image.

[image]

I use this code at my projects.

This code at Server Project:

```
[ClientRpc]
private void ChangeSceneA()
{
    NetworkManager manager = NetworkManager.singleton;
    manager.ServerChangeScene("SceneA");
}
```

This Code at Client A :

```
[ClientRpc]
private void ChangeSceneA()
{
    Debug.Log("SceneA Open");
}
```

This code at Client B:

```
private temp = 0; // to make call this function just aonce.

[ClientRpc]
private void ChangeSceneA()
{
    if (temp < 1)
    {
        NetworkManager manager = NetworkManager.singleton;
        manager.ServerChangeScene("SceneA");
    }

    temp = 1;　　　　
}
```

I got this error message from server project's console.

[image]

It says : There is already a player for this connection.
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)

Is there very nice guy to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. It was little bit easy.

Firstly I use this code to load new scene:

```
 SceneManager.LoadScene("SceneA");
```

And then, create GameObject variable as global:

```
[SerializeField]
private GameObject Player;
```

Set player at Unity editor and it will be player prefab that you set in here.
[image]

Finally, add this code at Start function then it's done.

```
private void Start()
{
    if(Player.activeSelf == true && isClient)
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(Player);
    }
}
```

※ I will keep this question for other people who will have same problem with me.